# Run TSC Task on Save Automatically in Visual Studio Code 0.5.0

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript1.5

I am migrating from `WebStorm` to `VSCode`, and this one thing I can't get, and it seems to be the most basic. Upon saving, I want to run my `typescript` task. I can't yet use `tsconfig.json` because I can't exclude folders yet with `filesGlob` the way it is done in `atom` (it chokes on my node_modules folder).

I have to do `CTRL+SHIFT+B` every time now, to get the red underlines to go away after every save. There must be a way?

Answer (score 2):

After lots of fiddling, I came up with this, which works the way I expect.

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [ "-p", "." ],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "isWatching": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "amd",
    "watch": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true
    },
    exclude: [ 'node_modules']
}
```

[Ultimate Visual Studio Code / TS Setup](http://thepetesmith.com/posts/the-ultimate-typescript-ide-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your keyboard short-cuts to build on each save - Code happily allows multiple bindings to the same key:

*keybindings.json*

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+s",          
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build" 
    }
]
```

You can get to these settings using File, Preferences, Keyboard Shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a gulpfile to reference all your tasks including the typescript compilation.

Then you add a "watch" task which launch the compilation.

Finally, you create a Task Runner file in VSCode to launch at build the "watch" task in gulp.

So when you open VSCode, you do `CTRL+SHIFT+B` and voila.